# how to build PHP/MySQL query to input data from a series of checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website that will show night club revelers events and night establishments in a big city.

A user should be able to add certain details when adding their event on the site e.g.(in the events table) `event_id, event_name, event_description, event_date, event_photo_url` etc.

I want users to be able to search or find certain events or establishments based on interests.  I have an interest table that looks like this.

interest_id,  interest-name
1, Shoot Pool
2,            Karaoke
3,            Lounge
4,            Live Band
5,            Dancing
6,            Watch Sports

So there are 6 checkboxes on my form. A user can select none, 1, 2 or all 6.

Should I have each checkbox submit individual values to my submit form, ie

```
input name="dancing" type="checkbox" value="5" 
input name="watch_sports" type="checkbox" value="6"
```

Or should I build an array

```
input name="interest[]" type="checkbox" value="5" 
input name="interest[]" type="checkbox" value="6"
```

I have a table to link events with interests ie;

```
event_interest table  
event_interest_id            
event_id              
interest_id
```

I have never implemented a series of check boxes before. Does anyone know the way to go about capturing user input and storing the values in my database?

Comment: Do you have any code built so far? If so, post that here for us. You should also go Accept a few Answers from your previous Questions..

Comment: @jnpcl. Unfortunately, no code so far.

Comment: Basically, if the checkboxes are for similar things, use an array of them. If they're not, then don't :-) Also, if you are going to serialise (serialize for you Americans ;-)) the checkbox data, it's much easier to use arrays of checkboxes. Also, just in case you didn't know, you can reference checkbox arrays by keys, like this:
`<input type="checkbox" name="boxArray[name]">`
If you knew already, my apologies for insulting your intelligence.

Comment: No problem! I aim to please... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get as POST or GET those checkbox values which are checked.

so u can do something like:

```
$interests = $_POST['interests'];
$event_id = intval($_POST['event_id']);//or where ever you get that from
foreach($interests as $interest){
    ....
    $interest = intval($interest);
    $query = "INSERT INTO event_interests  SET interest_id = $interest, event_id = $event_id";
    .... //send query to db
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I should use the array method for this. This helps a lot, thanks.